# How to load faster a big chunk of NSString to UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, nsstring

I am trying to load a big chunk of data by doing this:

```
NSString *bigchunk=@".....";

label1.text=bigchunk;//this line is causing my uitableview to jerky scrolling
```

Is there a way to load a big chunk of data to UILabel faster than setText in order to overcome the jerky scrolling at my uitableview?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Need...More...Details...

Comment: I have a custom uitableview cell with 6 objects on it. One of them is a label and i load more than 1000 characters in each uitableview cell row - I have the above code inside (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath . This is resulting to jerky scrolling. If you need more info let me know. Thanks for your respond.

Comment: Do you think that UITableView cells were designed to contain so much text?  Perhaps rethink your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section of this repository might interest you.

https://github.com/rnapier/ios5ptl/tree/master/ch05/TableViewPerformance

It shows you 3 ways of displaying `UITableView`s as a test to see which has the best performance. The method through subclassing `ABTableViewCell` (which is included in the repo) has the best performance. You would draw the `NSString` with `drawInRect:` or `drawAtPoint`. This also works (and as shown in the example) with `UIImage`s and others.

In the example linked above, you can test the different ways by commenting/uncommenting code in the `TableViewPerformanceViewController`.